# ng build works but not with --prod

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, compiler-errors, circular-dependency, production

My `> ng serve` or `> ng build` command doesn't produce any error and the application runs. but when I run `> ng build --prod`, it throws the below error. I tried to find a lot on the internet and tried many things like

- reordering the imports
- tried forwardRef
- find circular dependencies
- etc..

but still, the error persists.

> P.S.: **Downvoters**, please specify the solution first or any digestible
>   reason, or just skip this question without touching it as you can't
>   evaluate the situation. BUT **DON'T CREATE NUISANCE**.

```
C:\wamp\www\ngapp>ng build --prod
 10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 activeWarning: Can't resolve all parameters for LoginService in C:/wamp/www/ngapp/sr
c/app/abstract/login.service.ts: ([object Object], ?). This will become an error in Angular v6.x
Warning: Can't resolve all parameters for UserService in C:/wamp/www/ngapp/src/app/abstract/user.service.ts: ([object Ob
ject], ?). This will become an error in Angular v6.x

Date: 2018-06-30T06:40:13.988Z
Hash: 72312a1071e597367666
Time: 10125ms
chunk {scripts} scripts.385b291e179030219400.js (scripts) 136 kB  [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js (runtime) 1.05 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} styles.14764545cc77d1b25789.css (styles) 159 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.207dcc605630215505f5.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} main.f58b96bf9bf614ca37d4.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for UserService in C:/wamp/www/ngapp/src/app/abstract/user.service.ts: ([object
Object], ?).
```

**login.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, forwardRef, Inject } from '@angular/core';
//import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { NotFoundError } from '../errors/notfound-error';
import { Unauthorized } from '../errors/unauthorized-error';
import { AppError } from '../errors/app-error';
import * as GLOBAL from 'globals';


interface Credentials {
  username: string,
  password: string
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'  
})

export abstract class LoginService {


  // readonly USER_NOT_FOUND = 404;
  // readonly UNAUTHENTICATED = 401;

  private http: HttpClient;

  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => HttpClient)) http:HttpClient, private url: string) {    
    this.http = http;
  }

  check(credential: Credentials, url?) {
    url = url ? url : this.url;

    return this.http.post(url, credential)
      .pipe(
        //map((response) => { console.log(response.json()); return response.json() }),
        map((response) => { return response }),
        retry(0),
        catchError((error: Response) => { return this.handleError(error) })
      );
  }

  isUserExists(user: {username: string}, url?){

    url = url ? url : this.url;

    return this.http.post(url, user)//, {observe: 'response'})
      .pipe(
        map(response => { return response;}),
        catchError( error => this.handleError(error))
      )
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {    
    //console.log("handleError: ", error);
    if (error.status as number === GLOBAL.USER_NOT_FOUND) {      
      return throwError(new NotFoundError(error));
    }
    else if (error.status as number === GLOBAL.UNAUTHENTICATED) {      
      let e = new Unauthorized(error);      
      return throwError(e);
    }
    else {      
      return throwError(new AppError(error));
    }
  }
}
```

**auth.service.ts** extends LoginService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoginService } from '../abstract/login.service';
//import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService extends LoginService {  

  constructor(http: HttpClient) { 
    super(http, "http://demo1601932.mockable.io/login-invalid");  
  }

  isUserExists(user: {username: string}){
    let url;

    if (user.username == "cust@ngapp.com")
      url = "http://demo1601932.mockable.io/user-valid";
    else
      url = "http://demo1601932.mockable.io/user-invalid";

    return super.isUserExists(user, url);
  }

  check(user){

    let url;

    if (user.username == "cust@ngapp.com" && user.password == "cust1234")
      url = "https://demo1601932.mockable.io/login-valid";
    else
      url = "https://demo1601932.mockable.io/login-invalid";

      return super.check(user, url);
  }
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, forwardRef, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { NotFoundError } from '../errors/notfound-error';
import { Unauthorized } from '../errors/unauthorized-error';
import { AppError } from '../errors/app-error';
import * as GLOBAL from 'globals';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  private http: HttpClient;  

  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => HttpClient)) http:HttpClient, private url: string) {
    this.http = http;    
  }

  getAll(url? : string){

    url = url ? url : this.url;

    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map(response => { return response;}),
      catchError( error => this.handleError(error))
    )
  }

  getUser(uid, url? : string){
    url = url ? url : this.url;

    return this.http.get(url + "/" + uid)
    .pipe(
      retry(2),
      catchError( error => this.handleError(error))
    )
  }

  create(user, url? : string){  
    url = url ? url : this.url;

    return this.http.put(url, user).pipe(
      map(response => { return response;}),
      catchError( error => this.handleError(error))
    )
  }

  update(uid, data, url? : string){
    url = url ? url : this.url;

    return this.http.patch(url + '/'+ uid, data, { observe: "response"}).pipe(
      map(response => {
        // console.log('Headers', response.headers.keys());
        // console.log('Body', response.body);
        return response.body;
      }),
      retry(1),
      catchError( error => this.handleError(error))
    )
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {    
    //console.log("handleError: ", error);
    if (error.status as number === GLOBAL.USER_NOT_FOUND) {      
      return throwError(new NotFoundError(error));
    }
    else if (error.status as number === GLOBAL.UNAUTHENTICATED) {      
      let e = new Unauthorized(error);      
      return throwError(e);
    }
    else {      
      return throwError(new AppError(error));
    }
  }
}
```

**customer.service.ts** extends UserService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from '../abstract/user.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CustomersService extends UserService {

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http, "http://demo1601932.mockable.io/customers/");
  }

  getAll(){
    return super.getAll("http://demo1601932.mockable.io/customers/get");
  }

  get(uid){
    return super.getUser(uid, "http://demo1601932.mockable.io/customer/get");
  }

  create(user){
    return super.create(user, "http://demo1601932.mockable.io/customers");
  }

  update(uid, userData){
    return super.update(uid, userData, "http://demo1601932.mockable.io/customers");
  }

  //Admin
  getall4Admin(){
    return super.getAll("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  }

  get4Admin(uid){
    return super.getUser(uid, "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  }
}
```

If someone wants, I can post all 3 modules [admin, customers, app] module files code.

Comment: @user184994, the CustormerService class constructor calls the `super(http, "http://demo1601932.mockable.io/customers/");` as you can see the code.

Comment: Just noticed that, but you've marked it as `Injectable`, so the DI is trying to instantiate it. If you remove the `@Injectable`, it should be fine

Comment: Angular can't possibly inject a string (url) into the UserService. Remove that argument. Or, if this is just supposed to be a base class for other services, remove its Injectable decorator.

Comment: @user184994, in which files exactly? parent class or child class? can you specify with example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `UserService`, you've marked the Service as `@Injectable`, which means Angular needs to know how to instantiate it. It has no idea what you want to use for the URL.

If you don't want to inject `UserService` directly into constructors, then simply remove:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

from `UserService`.

Alternately, if you do want to inject into constructors, then remove the `url` property from the constructor, and set it using a `set`ter instead, by adding the below code into `UserService`

```
set url(url: string) {
    this.url = url;
}
```

And in child class constructor, set it with `super.url = "http://demo1601932.mockable.io/customers/"`

Comment: This answer is 99% on target. removing @Injectable surely is the mandatory step to resolve my issue. but I found that it removed the LoginSerive error but not UserService. then I found out that the UserService was imported into the relative module which must be removed too from the `admin.module.ts`
Additionally, the alternative way had some issue. `super.url=..` generated error then i set it to `this.url=..` in child class. but not sure it worked properly.